# Не выгружает картинки из папки assets; проект Ruby on rails

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, изображения

Проблема в том, что не выгружаться картинки из папки assets. Ни как бекграунд, ни просто как картинка

```
<img src="../images/table.jpg">
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

И [не должна](http://rusrails.ru/asset-pipeline).

> Файлы в app/assets никогда не отдаются напрямую в production.

Чтобы это работало так, как Вы хотите, изображение надо сохранить в `/public/images` тогда его можно будет получить по `/images/table.jpg`.
Чтобы получить файл из `app/assets` во вьюхе, нужно использовать хэлпер `asset_path`:

```
asset_path("table.jpg")
```

Если хотите применить при помощи css-стилей то придётся использовать `scss` и хэлпер `asset-path` в нём.

Например так:

```
// app/assets/stylesheets/main.scss
.my-selector {
    background-image: url(asset-path("table.jpg"));
}
```